# Using awk, how I do specify doing something only when the first field is an integer?

Tags: awk

I am just starting out in awk, and wonder, using awk, what is the proper way to state, do something (such as printing out the record) only when the first field is an integer?

Answer (score 4):

> do something ... only when the first field is an integer?

This does the command in braces, `print` in this case, only if the first field is a positive integer:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/{print;}'
```

Floating point numbers are rejected.

If we want to accept either positive or negative integers, then, as mklement0 suggests, use the following:

```
 awk '$1 ~ /^[+-]?[[:digit:]]+$/{print;}'
```

Note that, because `[:digit:]` is used, these tests are unicode safe.

Comment: Nicely done; more accurately, it matches _positive decimal_ integers, with any number of leading zeros (`awk`  treats `0`-prefixed number strings in input - e.g., `010`, `08` - as decimals too). If supporting negative integers and explicitly signed positive integers is also needed: `/^[+-]?[[:digit:]]+$/`.

Comment: @mklement0 wrt `awk treats 0-prefixed number strings in input - e.g., 010, 08 - as decimals too` you should add `by default`. gawk will treat numbers that start with zero and do not contain digits greater than 7 as octal if invoked with `--non-decimal-data`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Good tip, thanks; while we're at it: `gawk` is different in another respect, too: by default, it _does_ recognize octal and hex. number _literals inside a script_ - unless `--posix` is specified.

Comment: Why didn't you shorten it as `awk '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/'`?

Comment: @mklement0 Right (as of gawk 3.1) but that's a different situation, we're just talking about input data here.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I think because the OP asked how to "do something" and printing was just one example of something you could do.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R The OP asked about how to _"do something (such as printing out the record)"_ when `$1` is an integer.  Thus, printing the line was just an example.  I included `{print}` explicitly here with the explanation that, whatever the "something" was, it should be put inside those braces.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I see that Ed Morton replied while I was still writing.  Apologies for the repetition.